# Updating relationship of dependent object in unidirectional relationship in EF

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two types like this

```
public class Division
{

    public Division()
    {
        SubDiv = new List<EFTest.SubDivision>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<SubDivision> SubDiv { get; set; }


}

public class SubDivision : DomainObject
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

Now I have added a Division already in the database an have loaded it, and would like to add a new SubDivision to it, through the following code.

```
Division div = c.Divisions.Include(x => x.SubDiv).First();
SubDivision sub = new EFTest.SubDivision() { name = "d" };
div.SubDiv.Add(sub);
c.SubDivisions.Add(sub);
c.SaveChanges();
```

What this code does is that it adds a new SubDivision in the database, but with the column DivisionId (the FK column) set to NULL. So how do I make EF recognize and insert the relation between the Division and SubDivision without having to add a navigation property of FK field to the SubDivision class?

Comment: Are you mapping to existing db tables or they were created using EF migrations?

Comment: using code first migrations

Comment: Then there must be some fluent configuration (since the default FK column name would be `Division_Id`), can we see it?

Comment: It is 'Division_Id' you are right. There is no fluent config.

Comment: Then I can't reproduce your issue. Executing your code snippet as is (and even removing `c.SubDivisions.Add(sub);` line which is redundant) inserts `SubDivision` record with correct FK. Latest EF6.1.3 if that matters.

Comment: How is c.SubDivisions.Add(sub); is redundant, when I removed this line, the SubDivision itself was not inserted. I am also using EF6.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is fine. The problem is different.

Looks like you have turned context change tracking off. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with "standard" (default) context settings (the new record was inserted with the correct FK, even removing the normally redundant `c.SubDivisions.Add(sub);` line), but once I did `c.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`, then either no records was inserted (when removing the aforementioned redundant line), or using the original code the record was inserted with `NULL` FK.

To get the desired behavior, either keep change tracking on:

```
c.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; // <--
Division div = c.Divisions.Include(x => x.SubDiv).First();
SubDivision sub = new EFTest.SubDivision() { name = "d" };
div.SubDiv.Add(sub);
c.SaveChanges();
```

or explicitly call `DetectChanges` before `SaveChanges`:

```
c.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; // <--
Division div = c.Divisions.Include(x => x.SubDiv).First();
SubDivision sub = new EFTest.SubDivision() { name = "d" };
div.SubDiv.Add(sub);
c.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // <--
c.SaveChanges();
```